# Autonumbering and spacing for custom label using enumitem and enumerate

Tags: enumerate, enumitem

I would like auto numbering to continue after the custom label if possible?  I tried `setcounter{enumi}` but I don't know how to get the last auto number and then add one to it.

I would also like the single custom label aligned with all the other labels if possible.

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[66]

\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{Step \arabic*}:]
\addtolength{\itemindent}{1.65cm}

\item I like a clean look so I aligned Step 1 with the text.  This is what I want with all my steps.

\item [\textbf{Step 2 a)}:] I can manually put in Step 2 a): but how do I get it to align with Step 1 and the other steps?

%\setcounter{enumi}{2} Not sure how to set this dynamically

\item I really want this to be Step 3 without having to hardcode in Step 3 because I have a bunch more steps that I just want to be auto numbered.

\item \lipsum[66] % Should be step 4

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image: Alignment of custom label]

Comment: You can add `\stepcounter{enumi}` to the item with the custom number in order to increase the counter by one. Regarding the alignment: could you please specify more detailes, how the desired alignment should look like? You could left-align all 'Step's by adding the option `align=left` to the `enumerate` environment.

Comment: You can use `\addtocounter{enumi}{1}` to set the counter value relative to it's past value. By default the labels of an enuerate are aligned right.

Comment: Thank you!  align=left worked with the addtolength to get exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\SetLabelAlign{step}{\bfseries Step #1:\hfil}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[66]

\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*,align=step,itemindent=\leftmargini]

\item I like a clean look so I aligned Step 1 with the text.  This is what I want with all my steps.

\stepcounter{enumi}
\item [\theenumi{} a)] I can manually put in Step 2 a): but how do I get it to align with Step 1 and the other steps?

 Not sure how to set this dynamically

\item I really want this to be Step 3 without having to hardcode in Step 3 because I have a bunch more steps that I just want to be auto numbered.

\item \lipsum[66] % Should be step 4

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]